# Error al pasar fechas desde formulario padre a formulario hijo

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy tratando de pasar un periodo de fechas desde un formulario padre a los formulario hijos pero me da un erro que no he podido resolver, pongo el codigo que tengo.

Form Padre:

```
public IPeriodo date { get; set; }
 private void Anterior()
    {
        if(Per[0] > Convert.ToDateTime("2020/01/30"))
        {
            Per[0] = Per[0].AddDays(-7);
            Per[1] = Per[1].AddDays(-7);
            date.Fechas(Per[0].ToShortDateString(), Per[1].ToShortDateString());//error
            Mostrar();
        }
    }
```

En esta parte del código de formulario padre me surge un error que dice:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

y no se porque.

Interfaz:

```
public interface IPeriodo
{
    void Fechas(String FechaI, String FechaF);
}
```

Form Hijo:

```
public partial class frmAsistencia : Form, IPeriodo
{
    private String incioF;
    private String finF;

    void IPeriodo.Fechas(string FechaI, string FechaF)
    {
        this.incioF = FechaI;
        this.finF = FechaF;
    }
}
```

las variables de aquí las uso para realizar consultas a base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que conozco, una implementación explícita *(la que tú utilizas)* debe ser instanciada, porque ¿qué valor u objeto tiene la propiedad **date**?

Se tiene que inicializar esa propiedad, algo así:

```
date = new frmAsistencia();
```

Originalmente, cuando declaras la variable **date** el valor que posee, al no tener referencia alguna, es *NULL*; razón por la cual, cuando quieres usar un método o propiedad en **date**, te lanzará `NullReferenceException`, debido a que estás queriendo llamar a una variable que tiene como valor *NULL*

Comment: pero date es el nombre objeto para poder accesar al método de la interfaz, se supone que con esta linea "date.Fechas(Per[0].ToShortDateString(), Per[1].ToShortDateString());" yo le puedo pasar las fechas al método y así pasar las fechas al formulario hijo

Comment: Accedes a la interfaz, ¿pero de cuál objeto implementado? mira aquí en este link, una pequeña prueba: https://dotnetfiddle.net/c1yb0g

Comment: creo que nos desviamos del tema, mi pregunta era por que me daba el error en la parte de date.Fechas();

Comment: porque estas queriendo pasarle valor a un objeto no instanciado, que seria el objeto tuyo de interface. Como dijo mas arriba tenes que hacer asi:

public IPeriodo date { get; set; }
date = new frmAsistencia();

No le encuentro la logica a heredar la interface por lo menos en este ejemplo.